# Getting error while using ekspodoperator can only create pods with spec.nodeName set to itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, airflow, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have an airflow hosted on `eks` and I am trying to run a task using `EksPodOperator`, something like:

```py
task = EksPodOperator(
       dag=dag,
       task_id="start_pod",
       pod_name="test_pod",
       cluster_name="cluster-name",
       image="amazon/aws-cli:latest",
       cmds=["sh", "-c", "echo Test Airflow; date"],
       labels={"demo": "hello_world"},
       get_logs=True,
       is_delete_operator_pod=True,
       kubernetes_conn_id="kubernetes_cluster",
       annotations={"kubernetes.io/config.mirror": ""},
       affinity=k8s.V1Affinity(
           node_affinity=k8s.V1NodeAffinity(
               required_during_scheduling_ignored_during_execution=k8s.V1NodeSelector(
                   node_selector_terms=[
                       k8s.V1NodeSelectorTerm(
                           match_expressions=[
                               k8s.V1NodeSelectorRequirement(
                                   key="alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name",
                                   operator="In",
                                   values=["worker-uat"],
                               )
                           ]
                       )
                   ]
               )
           )
       ),
   )
```

But , even after trying multiple ways , i keep on getting error as :

```json
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': 'XXXXXXXXX', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': 'XXXXXX', 'Date': 'Wed, 26 Apr 2023 07:16:40 GMT', 'Content-Length': '313'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods \"test-pod-387fpfvu\" is forbidden: node \"ip-XXXXXXXXXXus-west-2.compute.internal\" can only create pods with spec.nodeName set to itself","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"name":"test-pod-387fpfvu","kind":"pods"},"code":403}
```

I am unable to figure out what exactly i am missing

Comment: I'm having similar issues, did you manage to sort it out?